# How do I intercept Wiremock requests and conditionally issue a response?

Tags: http, wiremock

I am using Wiremock to mock out two endpoints. Our deployment smoketest calls a third, diagnostic, endpoint on the app to test the health of the primary endpoints. I need to have the smoketest endpoint check that the other two endpoints are functioning, return a 200 for success and something else if not. This seems to be either stubbing out two possible results for a single endpoint *OR* not use stubbing at all. I can't find a callback mechanism in Wiremock that can issue the response but that seems to be what I need.

How do I do this in Wiremock?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to subclass `ResponseDefinitionTransformer` and build the conditional functionality into the `transform` override, which returns a `ResponseDefinition`.

You then need to pass an instance of the `ResponseDefinitionTransformer` subclass to the WireMockConfiguration decorator `extensions`.

If the transformer is not to be applied to every route you must override `ResponseDefinitionTransformer.applyGlobally` to return `false` and pass the name of the transformer to the `ResponseDefinitionBuilder` decorator `withTransformers`.

Here is some Scala that demonstrates this:

```
class RouteStubTransformer extends ResponseDefinitionTransformer {

  override def transform(
    request: Request,
    responseDefinition: ResponseDefinition,
    files: FileSource,
    parameters: Parameters): ResponseDefinition = {

    if (someGoodCondition) {
      new ResponseDefinitionBuilder()
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
        .withStatus(200)
        .withBody("""{"message":"ok"}""")
        .build()
    } else {
      new ResponseDefinitionBuilder()
        .withHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8")
        .withStatus(404)
        .withBody("""{"message":"page not found"}""")
        .build()
    }
  }

  override def getName: String = "stub-transformer"

  override def applyGlobally: Boolean = false
}

object WireMockApp {

  val routeStubTransformer = new RouteStubTransformer
  val wireMockConfiguration = WireMockConfiguration
    .options()
    .port(8080)
    .extensions(routeStubTransformer)
  val server = new WireMockServer(wireMockConfiguration)
  server.start()

  server.stubFor(get("/route/to/transform").willReturn(aResponse().withTransformers(routeStubTransformer.getName)))
}
```

Comment: Question is how do you intercept the incoming call? How do you make the condition based on the incoming call?